# spring mvc remember selected option in drop down

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a spring mvc form with a drop down and radio button. 
I want to redisplay the form for confirmation and the drop down and radio buttons are not retaining the selections in the command object. 
The drop down displays all the contents from the list but doesnt show the selected option from the command as 1st option.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

use the spring forms tags and set the `path` attribute to the name of the variable in which you are storing the radio and drop-down selections.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using `form:radiobutton` and not `form:input type="radio"`.